# Entering data from form into Database PDO

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I learned MySQL, created a form and had it working with the database. I was then told I should be doing it PDO with prepared statements, so I did some research on that and changed my code.

I now have the code right (I think) but I can't figure out how data gets input. As you can see on my code, I have the database creating the rows as the user submits the form. However the database just picks up on whatever is within the speech marks under `//insert a row` and `//insert another row`.

For example, right now if the user completes and submits the form, no matter what information they enter, I just get 'Joe' and 'joe@example.com' etc showing in my database. Obviously I need their answers, otherwise my form would be irrelavant (as would the data submission). Have I totally missed the mark or am I missing something silly? I've tried changing and researching but am struggling. Really new to all this.

FORM:

```
<form action="testsubmit-pdo.php" method="post">
<label>Student Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="name" required="required"       placeholder="Please Enter Name"/><br /><br />
<label>Student Email :</label>
<input type="email" name="stu_email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="john123@gmail.com"/><br/><br />
<label>Student City :</label>
<input type="text" name="stu_city" id="city" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Your City"/><br/><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO demo (stu_name, stu_email, stu_city)
VALUES (:stu_name, :stu_email, :stu_city)");
$stmt->bindParam(':stu_name', $stu_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':stu_email', $stu_email);
$stmt->bindParam(':stu_city', $stu_city);

// insert a row
$stu_name = "Joe";
$stu_email = "joe@example.com";
$stu_city = "Joeland";
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row
$stu_name = "Mary";
$stu_email = "mary@example.com";
$stu_city = "Maryland";
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

Comment: It is because you're not updating your variables with information from the `$_POST` array. For instance `$stu_name = $_POST[stu_name']` if the form's input `name="stu_name"`.

Comment: I don't really see what your goal is. Please show us your entire code and what results do you expect?

Comment: Now that you've posted your form read my first comment.

Comment: I have updated my question with my html form, too. Users fill in the form and that information gets sent to the database. That's what my goal is.

Comment: `$stu_name = "Joe";` What do you expect? That php automatically change this hard coded stuff?

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you give me an example of what I need to change? Sorry, totally new to this!

Comment: @Rizier123 No. As I explained I am totally new to this and am trying to work out what goes there. If I don't put anything there it gives me errors. I'm trying to establish what should be going there. Obviously i'm aware that by writing 'Joe' i'm telling it to insert that.

Comment: As an aside, if you wanted to run the code as it is, and insert two different records, you would need to rebind the variables for Mary. As it is, it will insert Joe twice, since the bound variables have not been updated for the second `execute()`.

Comment: @halfer The script works correctly. When you call `execute()`  it just takes the variable which you bind so if you changed the variable values it inserts another row

Comment: @Rizier123, thanks! I was aware MySQLi did that, but not PDO. Handy to know! `/me makes mental note`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this -

```
// insert a row
$stu_name = "Joe";
$stu_email = "joe@example.com";
$stu_city = "Joeland";
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row
$stu_name = "Mary";
$stu_email = "mary@example.com";
$stu_city = "Maryland";
$stmt->execute();
```

to this -

```
// insert a row
$stu_name = $_POST['stu_name'];
$stu_email = $_POST['stu_email'];
$stu_city = $_POST['stu_city'];
$stmt->execute();
```

Your form will place the values in PHP's POST array and you can access them by the name property from the form.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfectly. Really appreciate all your help; very new to this.

Comment: @user2132851 FYI: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php (If you have a form with get method you can access it with `$_GET` if it is post method it's `$_POST`; Just do `print_r($_POST);` to see the structure of the array)

Comment: Thank you! It's all becoming a little more clear. I'm relatively good with HTML and CSS, but PHP and databases is a whole new world!

Answer (score 3):

You post the data entered by the user to your php file

```
<form action="some_php_file.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="stu_name">
   <input type="email" name="stu_email">
  <input type="text" name="stu_city">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and in php code, first you need to check if the submit button is clicked

```
   //check if submit button is clicked
  If(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

  // set the PDO error mode to exception
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   // prepare sql and bind parameters
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO demo (stu_name, stu_email, stu_city)
    VALUES (:stu_name, :stu_email, :stu_city)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':stu_name', $stu_name);
   $stmt->bindParam(':stu_email', $stu_email);
   $stmt->bindParam(':stu_city', $stu_city);

    $stu_name = $_POST['stu_name'];
    $stu_email = $_POST['stu_email'];
    $stu_city = $_POST['stu_city'];
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "New records created successfully";
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
}
```