# Cannot post form, MySQL, PDO/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, pdo

I'm trying to get two input fields to post to my MySQL database with help from [this stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639506/entering-data-from-form-into-database-pdo) questions answers. However, I get no input in my db, or any error on my page. What Am I missing? The DB credentials work, as I also have an output of them on my page (not listed here)

I added this to the code from the other thread (as a cfg.php file later included):

```
<?php
class Database
{

    private $servername = 'mydomain.com';
    private $dbname = 'mydatabase';
    private $username = 'mydatabaseuser';
    private $password = 'mypassword';


    public function dbConnection()
    {


        $this->conn = null;
```

The code from the thread:

```
        //check if submit button is clicked
        If (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

                // set the PDO error mode to exception
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                // prepare sql and bind parameters
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email)
    VALUES (:name, :email)");
                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $stmt->execute();
                echo "New records created successfully";
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
            $conn = null;
        }
else { echo "Not set"; } //Added by suggestion from Funk Forty Niner in this thread
```

My ending:

```
    }
}
    ?>
```

The code for the forms:

```
<?php include 'cfg.php' ?>





<div class="container">
    <div class="container__item">
        <form class="form"  method="post"> <!-- updated with method as suggested by RamRaider in this thread -->
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form__field" placeholder="Your name" style="margin-bottom:10px;"/><br> <!-- updated from name-type to text-type as suggested by Funk Forty Niner and RamRaider in this thread -->
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form__field" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--inside uppercase">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you didn't follow that Q&A exactly as posted. Error reporting would be your friend here.

Comment: Tell you what; add an `else { echo "Not set"; }` to your `If (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` and you will see for yourself that you will get a "Not set" echo'd.

Comment: One of your inputs isn't a valid input tag, not even in HTML 5.

Comment: Thank you! Error reporting is/was On at level E_ALL, and it works when I removes the closing bracket for example. I noticed the input tag error "name" now, thanks! PhpStorm even pointed it out, but I didn't look -_- Still doesn't work though, and no errors. Even added the else statement. Could it be because it's a button and not an input field? /: Also added method="post"  as suggested by RamRaider below.

Comment: Welcome. Well, the button has a submit type, so that should work. See Ram's answer for now and comment under it to get more help. Make sure your query does fire up and has the right connection.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form class="form">
```

By default this will use `GET` as the method

Change to

```
<form class="form" method='post'>
```

and, compliments to @Funk Forty Niner for being more diligent and pointing out the mistook with one of the form input elements

```
<input type="name" ...
```

should most likely be

```
<input type="text" ...
```

---

**EDIT**

Following on from previous advice regarding form element types and having read your comments I hope the following might be of help.

Whatever you have in that `Database` class seems to bring nothing to the party - it is not used in your code when you are actually attempting the `insert`

For the connection script `db.php` I suggest saving in the `inc` folder - store all the other classes and scripts that get re-used in the same location.

```
example directory structure

Directory of C:\wwwroot\public\html

20/01/2018  18:08    <DIR>          .
20/01/2018  18:08    <DIR>          ..
20/01/2018  18:07    <DIR>          assets
20/01/2018  18:08    <DIR>          content
20/01/2018  18:07    <DIR>          css
20/01/2018  18:07    <DIR>          images
20/01/2018  18:07    <DIR>          inc
20/01/2018  18:07    <DIR>          scripts
```

So, when you need to include files ( such as your db connection script ) use `set_include_path` like this before using `include` or `require`

```
set_include_path 'C:\wwwroot\public\html\inc';
include 'db.php';
/*etc*/
```

-

```
<?php

    $verbose=false;

    try{

        /*

            database connection script
            --------------------------
            db.php

        */

        $dbuser='root';
        $dbpwd='p4$$w0rD';
        $dbhost='localhost';
        $dbname='geronimo';


        /* optional attribibutes for the connection */
        $options=array( 
            PDO::ATTR_CURSOR                    =>  PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT                =>  false,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY  =>  true,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES          =>  false,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND        =>  "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', @@sql_mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES, @@foreign_key_checks = 1"
        );
        $dsn='mysql:host='.$dbhost.';port='.$dbport.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf-8';


        $conn=new PDO( $dsn, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $options );

    }catch( PDOException $e ){
        exit( $verbose ? $e->getTraceAsString() : 'Database connection error' );
    }

?>
```

And the code to process the form submission

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'] ) ) {
        try{
            /*

                Include the database connection. The path used to this
                needs careful attention

            */
            include 'db.php';

            $name=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            $email=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );


            $sql='insert into `subscribers` (`name`, `email`) values ( :name, :email )';
            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

            if( $stmt ){

                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name );
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email );

                $result=$stmt->execute();
                echo $result ? 'ok' : 'fu manchu say ver bad foo';

            } else {
                throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql query');
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sure... but you missed something here. Look at their inputs again ;-)

Comment: right enough - didn't really look too much further than the form tag...

Comment: thanks for the plug ;-) now all that's left would be if that connection's happening. Seeing their class, is unsure if that's working at all and seems to have missing code for it. Well, the ball is in the OP's court now, as it were ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the input! Still returns nothing, not even an error. Error reporting is working (checked by removing last butterfly bracket in cfg.php). I just get nothing in my db. Applied all of your suggested changes (and Funky Forty Niner's).

Comment: can you add the real code from cfg.php -  is that being used at all?

Comment: @RamRaider the first code is the real (and complete) code, except for my usernames and password of course. That is working though, as I use it to actually retrieve the data in the database below the form (for now).

Comment: that cannot be the complete code... it just sort of stops

Comment: The code used to output data from the database is somewhere else, if that's what you mean. The first part I clipped from another site I have, as the other overflowthread never included how to implement the actual database connection. I've tried modifying the end/start of it to check if something was too much, with no luck. If you don't mean the code for the output, and just this (for the form input), please elaborate why it cannot stop there. I'm really new to this (hence getting my code at stackoverflow to begin with)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scrapping it all instead and using the following instead from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UystTZ0PPjY) as I'm not that well versed with this yet. In the end, I couldn't even figure out how to use variables for the credidentials and storing them somewhere else for re-usage:

**cfg.php:**

```
<?php
// Insert data into mysql database called "subscribers" using PDO

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
try {
$pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=mydomain.com;dbname=mydatabase", "myusername", "mypassword");
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
}

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `subscribers`(`name`, `email`) VALUES (:name,:email)";
    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":name"=>$name,":email"=>$email));

    if($pdoExec)
    {
        echo 'Thank you for your submission!';
    } else {
        echo 'Your sumission failed!';
    }
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__item">
        <form class="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form__field" required placeholder="Your name" style="margin-bottom:10px;"/><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form__field" required placeholder="Your E-Mail Address" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--inside uppercase">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Next mystery: How would I go about moving the echo to a div in index.php?

Comment: I moved the whole code from if($pdoExec to the closing bracket of the second echo into my index.php. I get ""Unexpected variable: pdoExec in ..../index.php on line XX"" though. When submitting the form however, the success message is shown and no error...

Comment: Solved it! I figured out that my if/else statement was outside of the old     "if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {", so wrapping it in "    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {" wherever else I use it solved it.